# Populating combo box from SQL database records

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

For now, I have this code but it is neither working nor returning errors.

How would I get all the records in the database to display it in the combo box?

```
Private Sub cmbCategory_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCategory.Click
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
    sqlconn.Open()
    myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT CAT_ID FROM tblOfficeEquipmentCategory)", sqlconn)
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: does it shows the message box?

Comment: im sorry sir it is not included anymore.  when i clicked the drop down combo box it hangs and display a error

error:Run-time exception thrown : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra bracket, try this:

myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT CAT_ID FROM tblOfficeEquipmentCategory", sqlconn)

Answer (score 0):

Please put your select statement to a query browser and `RUN` it `BEFORE` telling your code is having any problem. This should be a MUST DO practice when dealing with database related web programming.

It is obvious that there is an extra ")" in your SQL statement.

Comment: i cannot get the correct where to input " on the ("SELECT CAT_ID FROM tblOfficeEquipmentCategory)", sqlconn) part

Comment: it does not return error sir, in sql query builder, it display the data i need. but in vb i got that error

Comment: SQL statements starts with and ends with double quotes "

Comment: so please check the contents inside your new SqlCommand and copy only the contents inside double quotes and put it to the query browser for trial run.

Comment: downvoting without commenting is not a good practice. Please state your reason of downvoting

Comment: im sorry sir, its not me that downvoting. someone used my computer and left it unlocked

Comment: @ivandinglasan I do not mean that you are the one downvoting. Instead I also don't know who downvoted it but downvoting without reasoning is not a good practice.